# C stack overflow HASKELL , while handling strings

Tags: list, haskell, combinatorics, partition

I want to find all the possible partitions of a string into a list of non-empty strings.

For example if i give as input `"sun"`,
i want to create this output : `[["s","u","n"], ["s","un"], ["su","n"], ["sun"]]`.

I have created a simple function with recursion but it prints this *overflow* error i can't fix it please i need help:

```
partition :: String->[[String]]

partition w = [[(head w)]:fix | fix <- partition (tail w)]
    ++[((head w):fix):fixfix | (fix:fixfix)<-partition (tail w)]
```

Comment: Recommendation: try evaluating this with pencil and paper on a small input, say, `""`, and seeing if you can see what stack is growing on your piece of paper.

Comment: I think this one is really *tricky* to see when you are not used to laziness and the way/when stuff is evaluated/forced - compare yours to the same where you prepend `[[head w]] : `in front of the two lists .. what happens now? *Hint*: when do you actually force `head w`? The first thing you will do when evaluating is trying to get the list into `_ : _` form (`_` is some thunk) and for `++` you do by evaluating the left side first - for the list-comprehension you need `fix`first ...

Comment: btw: if you enable `BangPatterns` (:set -XBangPatterns` in ghci) - you get somewhat what you probably had imagined by `partition !w = ...` this one will point you to you problem rather quickly I think

Comment: also: whenever you use `head` and `tail` you should ask yourself if you can rewrite this with `partition (h:tl) = ..` instead - it's much more obvious where you run into problems and it's usually easier to write the recursive functions on list this way too

Comment: @Carsten Even with strict evaluation this code has a big issue.

Comment: yes - I was trying to help OP figure it out themself

Answer (score 3):

The essential problem is that you're missing the base case for the recursion, so you have an infinite loop.

The simple thing is just to replace the `head`/`tail` mess with pattern matching, which will solve that problem as a side effect.

```
partition [] = [[]]
partition (w:ws) =
  [[w]:fix | fix <- partition ws] ++
  [(w:fix):fixfix | (fix:fixfix)<-partition ws]
```

This turns out to work okay, somewhat to my surprise. Why was I surprised? I figured that, with optimization, GHC would use common subexpression elimination to rewrite it to

```
partition [] = [[]]
partition (w:ws) =
    [[w]:fix | fix <- partitionws] ++
    [(w:fix):fixfix | (fix:fixfix)<-partitionws]
  where partitionws = partition ws
```

That would be bad: it would save the entire `partition ws` calculation across the `++`, using lots of memory. But it seems GHC is clever enough these days not to do that.

To be more confident, you can avoid the common subexpression, by accumulating a "continuation" explaining how you'll process each element you produce.

```
part :: ([[a]] -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
part f [] = f []
part f (w:ws) =
  part (\fix -> f ([w]:fix)) ws ++
  part (\q -> case q of
    [] -> []
    fix:fixfix -> f ((w:fix):fixfix)) ws

partition = part (:[])
```

For reasons I don't know, this version is a couple times faster than the simple one.

---

If you don't care about the order in which the elements are produced, you can avoid the space leak risk much more simply (and perhaps even faster) by doing something like this:

```
partition [] = [[]]
partition (w:ws) =
  [ q
  | m <- partition ws
  , q <- ([w]:m) : [(w:fix):fixfix | fix:fixfix <- [m]]]
```

This is almost as simple as the simplest solution.